# Ensuring encrypted string doesn't contain /

Tags: encryption, encoding

```cs
public static string Encryptor(string plainText, string EncryptionKey)
    {
        byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);

        Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length);
            cs.Close();
        }
        plainText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

        return plainText;
    }
```

this is the code I use to make filenames safe but the problem is that sometimes characters such as `/`  which is not acceptable for file creating and if I want to open it, `System.IO.FileStream` detects the part behind `/` as a folder which clearly doesn't exist.

I'm fairly new to `Aes` So what can I do to make sure `/` will not appear in the ciphered code?

Comment: Instead of traditional base64 you could use the 'filename-safe' version; see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks, how can I use that in c#? I couldn't find anything on google

Comment: I just found it, inside `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`

Comment: It is probably better known as base64url, it simply replaces `+` and `/` with `-` and `_`  respectively and doesn't use `=` for padding. It's of course more performant than first using base 64 and then replacing / removing those characters.

Comment: By the way, I'd strongly suggest using SHA-512 instead of SHA-1 if you're going to extract 48 bytes from `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`.